# Pointer crashing while returning - C

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to fully understand pointers, and so I am working on the exercises of Kenneth's A. Reek book, "Pointers On C."
I encountered an issue while working on chapter 6 problem 1 that says:
"Write a function that will search a string for any one of a given set of characters. you function should match this prototype

```
 char *find_char(char const *source, char const *chars);
```

This is my question: Inside this while loop,

```
while(*found_char_location != '\0'){

    if(*found_char_location == *source_pt_cpy)
    {
        return found_char_location;
        //return *source_pt_cpy;
    }//end if
```

the program gives me a segmentation fault error if I try to return the pointer ***source_pt_cpy** but it will work fine, if I return pointer ***found_char_location** which is very confusing, because don't they have the same value? Why would one crash but the other one won't?
Here is my complete source code. thanks for the help in advance.

```
char *find_char(char const *source, char const *chars)
{

  if(is_null(source, chars))
  {

    return NULL;
  }//end if

  char *found_char_location;
  char *source_pt_cpy;

  found_char_location = chars;

  source_pt_cpy = source;

  while(*found_char_location != '\0'){

    if(*found_char_location == *source_pt_cpy)
    {
      return found_char_location;
      //return *source_pt_cpy;
    }//end if

    source_pt_cpy++;

    if(*source_pt_cpy == '\0')
    {
      chars++;
      source++;
      found_char_location = chars;
      source_pt_cpy = source;
    }//end if

  }//end while

  return NULL;
}//end function
```

Comment: Just my opinion, comments like `\\end if`, `\\end while`, `\\end function` only makes your code less readable, especially when the code blocks are small.

Comment: I see, I always thought this would make the code clearer, ha. Noted, I will change this, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The things they POINT TO are the same value, but they are not at the same location (or you wouldn't need to check for their values being the same).

Also, be careful about using *; *source_pt_cpy isn't a pointer, its what that pointer points to, and if that's what you were returning, then using that value as a pointer could very likely cause a seg fault.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense, thanks for your help Scott!

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault is probably being caused by `find_char` but occuring in the caller of the function. Notice that in one case (the case that works) you are returning a pointer and the caller probably expects a pointer, since that is what is correct:

```
return found_char_location;
```

In the case that fails you aren't returning a pointer, but actually just a character that the pointer is pointing to:

```
return *source_pt_cpy;
```

So if the caller treats this as a pointer, that would likely cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks a lot mbratch, I need to keep practicing, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the ***chars** string will be shorter than the ***source** string.

You should be looping through **chars** for a fixed position in **source**

And if no match is found advance to the next position in source using **source++**

BUT

Return to the start of **chars**

Using something like:

```
chars = beginChars ;
```

Which you are not doing.

If you are unsure of what is happening add:

```
printf(" %c %c\n",*source,*chars);
```

In the middle of you loop, after all increments and decrements.

Answer (score 0):

In C, a pointer is the address of a varible, nothing else. If you want to compare strings (translated as **null terminated character strings** in C), you better use `strcmp()` or `strncmp()` functions.

A statement like this

```
  char *found_char_location;
  char *source_pt_cpy;

  found_char_location = chars;

  source_pt_cpy = source;
  ...
  ...
    if(*found_char_location == *source_pt_cpy)
```

would compare single values stored in locations pointed by `found_char_location` and `source_pt_cpy` pointers, in this case a character, and I think this is not what you are after!

Here is a code snippet from [a home-brewed string library I maintain](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString) (have a look at it if you want to have fun with pointers!)

```
/*******************************************************************
*  Return values
*      - NULL in case any of the arguments is NULL
*      - Modified string is returned 
*
*  Example Usage
*      char str[] = "'free' as in 'free speech', not as in 'free beer'";
*      printf("%s\n",zstring_replace_str(str,"free","KLMN"));
*
*  Example Output
*      'KLMN' as in 'KLMN speech', not as in 'KLMN beer'";
******************************************************************/
char *zstring_replace_str(char *str, const char *x, const char *y){
    /* to preserve the address of original pointers, tmp_ are used 
     * dummy_ptr enables us to preserve the address of tmp_str when
     * a matching string pattern is found
     * */
    char *tmp_str = str, *tmp_x = x, *dummy_ptr = tmp_x, *tmp_y = y;
    int len_str=0, len_y=0, len_x=0;

    /* NULL pointer check */
    if ((*str && *x && *y)==0)
        return 0;

    /* calculating length of strings */
    for(; *tmp_y; ++len_y, ++tmp_y)
        ;

    for(; *tmp_str; ++len_str, ++tmp_str)
        ;

    for(; *tmp_x; ++len_x, ++tmp_x)
        ;

    /* Bounds check */
    if (len_y >= len_str)
        return str;

    /* reset tmp pointers */
    tmp_y = y;
    tmp_x = x;

    for (tmp_str = str ; *tmp_str; ++tmp_str)
        if(*tmp_str == *tmp_x) {
            /* save tmp_str */
            for (dummy_ptr=tmp_str; *dummy_ptr == *tmp_x; ++tmp_x, ++dummy_ptr)
                if (*(tmp_x+1) == '\0' && ((dummy_ptr-str+len_y) < len_str)){
                    /* Reached at the end of x, we got something to replace 
                     * then!
                     * Copy y only if there is enough room for it
                     */
                    for(tmp_y=y; *tmp_y; ++tmp_y, ++tmp_str)
                        *tmp_str = *tmp_y;
            }
        /* reset tmp_x */
        tmp_x = x;
        }

    return str;
}
```

It does not exactly do what you want but will give you an idea how you can achieve your task.

In the code above, the `for` loop

`for (dummy_ptr=tmp_str; *dummy_ptr == *tmp_x; ++tmp_x, ++dummy_ptr)`

does what you want. It starts from the begining of source string (the initialization of `for` loop) and then compares *current characters pointed by pointers **tmp_x and dummy_ptr*** in its logical check part. Finally, the loop increments both pointers to traverse the whole strings.

Here is another example that *searches a char* rather than a string within a character string. This code is also from [zString library](https://github.com/fnoyanisi/zString).

```
/* First if check can be omitted to improve the performance */
int zstring_search_chr(char *token,char s){
    if (!token || s=='\0')
        return 0;

    for (;*token; token++)
        if (*token == s)
            return 1;

    return 0;
}
```